# How do I test the time images take to load using a javascript loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I am trying to perform some tests to see how long different images take to return to my browser. I am using a javascript for loop. However, The loop seems to run before the first image is loaded and the return does not give an accurate answer. Below is my code:

```
for (var radius=1; radius<10; radius++)
{
var startTime = new Date().getTime();
var img = new Image();

img.onload = function() {
    var loadtime = new Date().getTime() - startTime;
    console.log("image with radius: "+radius+" took " + loadtime + "ms to load");
};


url="http://test"+radius+"test2.com";
img.src = url; 
}
```

As a result, I get:

```
image with radius: 10 took 175ms to load 
image with radius: 10 took 368ms to load 
image with radius: 10 took 463ms to load 
image with radius: 10 took 608ms to load 
image with radius: 10 took 751ms to load 
image with radius: 10 took 895ms to load 
image with radius: 10 took 1038ms to load 
image with radius: 10 took 1181ms to load 
image with radius: 10 took 1324ms to load
```

I tried different methods of trying to get the loop to run only after each image is loaded without any success. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Do you know this is built into the browser already in the [network tab](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/network)?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example This will solve your `radius: 10` problem, but it won't cause the images to load one after the other. To do that, you'll need to use a queue that pops after each `load` event. Right now, you are telling the browser to fetch **all of the images at once**, but I suspect you want to wait for image *n* to load before you fetch *n+1*.

Comment: Times seem to be realistic, but your radius is logged from the radius variable after all iterations, i.e. 10. You will have to add a variable in your loop to keep the right radius value: `var uniqueRadius = radius;` and use this `uniqueRadius` in your `console.log` call.

Comment: Moreover, don't hesitate to write `+new Date` instead of `new Date().getTime()`

Comment: Ahh - ok I managed to get this going by just creating a normal function and calling that same function after complete. Much easier than a for loop. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put the `radius` and the `startTime` variables in a closure, otherwise you will always refer to the same variable:

```
function getLoadhandler(starttime, logmsg) {
    return function() {
         // get the local variables
         console.log(logmsg+": "+(starttime-Date.now()));
    };
}

for (var radius=1; radius<10; radius++) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = getLoadhandler(Date.now(), "Load time of image with radius "+radius);
    img.src = "http://test"+radius+"test2.com";
}
```